# Label a line graph above each point on the line with its value python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a plot with a bar and line graph on different y axes. I need to label the line graph with its values just above each point on the line. I've tried something like this

```
for p in ax2.patches:
    w,h = p.get_width(), p.get_height()
    x = p.get_x()
    ax2.text(x + w/2, h * 1.1, 
             f'{h}', va='center', ha='center')
```

which is a structure I used to label the bar graph. I also tried the example listed on this page https://queirozf.com/entries/add-labels-and-text-to-matplotlib-plots-annotation-examples, but couldn't figure it out since the examples are just using two series to generate the plot.

My code and graph is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

width=.7

t=pd.DataFrame({'bars':[3.4,3.1,5.1,5.1,3.8,4.2,5.2,4.0,3.6],'lines':[2.4,2.2,2.4,2.1,2.0,2.1,1.9,1.8,1.9]})
ax1 = t['bars'].plot(kind='bar',width=width,color='lightgrey')
ax2 = t['lines'].plot(secondary_y=True, color='red')
ax1.plot(label='bars')
ax2.plot(label='lines')
lines,labels=ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2,labels2=ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax2.legend(lines+lines2,labels+labels2)

ax1.yaxis.grid(linestyle='dashed')
ax1.set_axisbelow(True)
ax1.set_xticklabels(('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))
ax1.set_ylim(0,6)
ax1.set_ylabel('title1')
ax2.set_ylim(0, 2.5)
ax2.set_ylabel('title2')

plt.show()
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for x,y in t["lines"].items():
    plt.annotate(f"{y:.1f}", (x,y), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(0, 5), ha="center")
```